# Joomla - Newly added usre register field value is not in the getUser()

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I've added new field call `user_type` to the `users` table in joomla 2.5 user component. 
And updated 'libraries\joomla\user\user.php' file and `.xml` file for the new filed.

When I register with new filed it will work fine and update the new database field with new form value. But when it call `getUser()` array that new field value is empty.
I just print the array as

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
print_r($user);
```

All other fields have value like below:

```
JUser Object
(
    [isRoot:protected] => 
    [id] => 231
    [name] => miu
    [usre_type] => 
    [username] => miu
    [email] => s@l.test
```

Why that `usre_type` field value not come to the array? Is there any file, getUsre() need to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is a typo.

You added a column in the database table called `user_type`, however the array displays `usre_type`. Note the `r` and the `e` are the wrong way round.

Check the **user.php** and .**xml** file and correct this mistake

Comment: oh..! MY GOD..!! That is stupid careless mistake. Thanks for point out this.

Comment: no worries, we all make small mistakes like this :) Please accept the answer if this solved your problem